# A chord progression from Leavitt: how to analyze the diminished chord

Tags: chord-theory, functional-harmony

The question below is referred to W. Leavitt - *Getting up there* (duet), Vol. 2

The piece is in key of C. In the last system, upper staff, we have the following chord progression:

C  A-6  A-7  F  Gdim  G7  C

In terms of functional harmony, what role does that Gdim play?

I found:

I    VI6    VI7    IV   Gdim?  V7    I

Thank you for your support[image]

Comment: Appears to be for guitar(s).

Answer (score 4):

Steven Laitz calls this a **common-tone diminished seventh chord**, which is labeled "c.t.<sup>o</sup><sub>7</sub> to distinguish it from other uses of diminished chords.<sup>1</sup> (See also Wikipedia's [Diminished Seventh chord: other functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminished_seventh_chord#Other_functions).) Its function is to "*maintain the root of the harmony they extend*".<sup>2</sup> Here is a reproduction of Laitz's Example 35.17A, which illustrates the process:

```
X:0
T:Steven Laitz, The Complete Musician, 2008
T:Example 35.17A (p. 820)
K:A
M:none
L:1/4
%%score V1 (V2 V3)
[V:V1] "A:"y "I"E y "c.t.o7/V"E- y "V43"E
[V:V2 clef=bass] y [A,C] y [=G,C] y [^G,D]
[V:V3 clef=bass] y A,, y ^A,, y B,,
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Laitz, Steven G, 2008, *The Complete Musician*, New York: Oxford University Press, p. 820. Laitz is not alone in this. For example, see Aldwell, Edward, and Carl Schachter, 1989, *Harmony and Voice Leading*, 2nd ed., Fort Worth: Harcourt Brace Jovanovich College Publishers, pp. 516–519.
<sup>2</sup> Ibid. (Laitz's italics).

Comment: Reading the resource you kindly provided, I find that in the case of my example that  G°7  chord (or  Bb°7  chord)  is the #vi°7  resolving to  V7. Is it right?

Comment: @LeoAn My apologies for missing your question until now. The chord is labeled C.T.o7 in order to avoid the problem of assigning it a scale-based name. So while one could think of the chord as being built on #6 (or #1, 3, or 5, or any enharmonically equivalent pitch, like b7), that scale degree (and others) either aren't assigned a meaning in tonal theory, or their meaning doesn't align with the role of the common-tone chord. C.T.o7 clarifies the role of the chord without ambiguity.

Comment: @LeoAn You might also find this Q&A regarding #vi helpful: [Name of #vio7 in chord progression?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/108600/name-of-vio7-in-chord-progression/108657#108657).